# Boolean expression for a multiple of 2

Tags: java, boolean, expression

I need a Boolean expression for number of cylinders. The number must be greater than or equal to 4. Also it needs to be a multiple of 2. The cylinders can only be integers so no decimals.
So far I have
numCylinders => 4
But im unsure about the multiple of 2.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the modulo operator to ensure it's a multiple of two, and use the logical AND operator to tie the conditions together:

```
numCylinders >= 4 && numCylinders % 2 == 0
```

Modulo finds a remainder of a division operation. In the code above, if the remainder is zero, the number is divisible by 2.